# EF stored procedure returns integer instead of ObjectResult

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I have an issue while using a stored procedure in my MVC + EF application. This stored procedure returns 7 columns but when i add this to my edmx file by updating model from database. It returns only int value. I have other stored procedures as well but they return "ObjectResult" but this stored procedure returns only integer. I want to mention that it did not create any complex type.
Please suggest how i can fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why this happens but I found a work around.
It looks like that the EF gives back the count of affected rows. So it works well to set `NOCOUNT` to `ON` in the stored procedure.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

-- Your Code with a returning SELECT
SELECT * FROM MyTable

SET NOCOUNT OFF
```

After changing the procedure you need to update your Model from your Database.